# How do I automatically find out the name of the function I am currently viewing in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

This is a simple problem with a potentially simple solution (maybe there is a plugin that will help or a better way of working with the tool).

I have a large Python file with many function definitions that look very similar. Each definition is a few hundred lines long. When I'm trying to make sense of a few lines of code I often want to know which function definition those lines of code belong to. My current method for doing this is scrolling back up the file (I'm using PyCharm) until I reach the start of the function definition. This is tedious and time consuming. Is there a better way of determining which function I am currently viewing?

Comment: memorisation may be !

Comment: That suggests that your functions are too long - if you can't see the whole thing at once, refactor to more, smaller functions. If they *"look very similar"*, you should attempt to factor out that similarity, too.

Comment: Good advice. However, it is legacy code written by other people who don't care about readability. I don't have a photographic memory either :-) .

Comment: try file structure view https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/viewing-structure-of-a-source-file.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method called *Context info* (found under *View* menu) and bind to **CTRL  + SHIFT + Q** on OSX and **ALT + Q** on Linux. It will flash you the current class, function, etc, parents of the current cursor position at at the top of code editor.

(Basically it shows the same line if you would scroll up manually).

[image]

Comment: On Linux and Windows, the shortcut is `ALT` + `Q`. For more information see [this help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/viewing-current-caret-location.html?search=context%20info)

Answer (score 2):

Press `Ctrl-Shift-(Numpad Minus)`. It will collapse all the functions, putting your cursor back to the start of the current function. Then press `Ctrl-Shift-(Numpad Plus)` and you will get back where you were before. Or you can use `Ctrl-(Numpad Minus)` and collapse only the function you are in now.